# Why am I getting [] in the json response in postman always?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

// controllers/users.js
    'use strict';

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('Users');

exports.list_all_users = function(req, res) {
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(users);
    });
};


// exports.list_all_users = function(req, res){
//  res.send("display all users");
// };

exports.create_a_user = function(req, res){
    res.send("user_created");
};


exports.delete_a_user = function(req, res){
    res.send("user_deleted");
};
```

**./routes/users.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
    var users = require('../controllers/users');
    // users Routes
    app.route('/users')
        .get(users.list_all_users);
}
```

**model/UserModel.js**

```
'use strict';
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id:{
        type : Number,
        auto : true },
    name: {
        type    : String,
        required: 'Kindly enter the name '
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: 'Kindly enter the mailId '
    },
  role:{
        type: String,
      required : 'Enter a valid role '
  },
  invitedBy: {
        type: Number,
      required : 'Valid number'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

**server.js**

```
  var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        User  = require('./model/UserModel'), //created model loading here
        bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    // mongoose instance connection url connection

    var dbConfig        = require('./db');

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(dbConfig.config);


    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());


    var userRoutes = require('./routes/users'); //importing route
    userRoutes(app); //register the route


    app.listen(port);


    console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

I tried printing 'display as respone' to  response and it works, the database connection is successful.

But when I try to get from the db, it prints[] for /users get

I suspect something is wrong with my model

Can anyone point out what went wrong here ?

***My collection:
 collection : "Users"***

```
{
    "_id": 112,
    "name": "abcd",
    "password": "hash12341234",
    "email": "questioner@hotmail.com",
    "role": "musician",
    "invitedBy": 1
}
```

Comment: which framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In you controllers/user.js, you have tried to created a user model again. Can you try importing as follows,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = require('../model/UserModel')
```

In you userModel.js, you need to also place a connection string

```
var db            = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/XXXXX");
var Schema        = mongoose.Schema;
```

Comment: Still returns []

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace a line in `controller/user.js`

Use:

```
User = require('../model/UserModel')
```

instead of:

```
User = mongoose.model('Users');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still returns []

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is that, the get function is returning the objects in collection created only using the model in Node.

I tried creating the user with the api and tested get users but it works like charm.

I am still puzzled about why it is unable to return the objects from the collection which were created by me manually.